# How send the javascript value form a counterbutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, send

I'm new to languages like javascript an jquery and i really need you help by this. I want a button that counts the clicks and then send that end value to my email together with the name and email from the person.

this is my working button:

```
<button type="button" style="cursor:pointer" id="countButton">Klik Mij <span id="displayCount">0</span>
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");
button.onclick = function () {
    count++;
    display.innerHTML = count;
}
</script>
<br>
<br>
</div>
<form method="post" action="?">
    <label for="naam">Je Naam:</label>
    <input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" class="tekst" placeholder="naam" />
    <label for="email">Je Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="tekst" placeholder="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="verzenden" id="verzenden" class="reset" />
</form>
```

Is it possible to send this to my mail?
thanks in advance

Comment: which framework u work on? Dotnet, php? You will have to use server side script for this?

Comment: Not with JavaScript only. You need to send the data to the server that sends the mail.

Comment: You want to submit this form to server and server will send you a email including that data, right? But the data you send to sever does not include the count data. The count is stored in a span which is not a element in the form.

Comment: Check this link for PHP. http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways .
First from the server side and second from client side.

From the **client side** you can send it by using "[mail to](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto):" but this will use  gmail, yahoo or any other mailing server authentication or if "windows Live" is configured  in you computer then by that also.